# Lazy load multiple projects (in CLI workspaces) to one single big app

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, frontend, angular-cli-v6

Is it possible to lazy load multiple projects (created trough the new CLI generate application feature) into one big application ?

Where i work we have multiple projects, different teams work on them, and then each application is served separately but they are all small apps of a bigger app. So, each time you navigate between apps, you will have to wait for the loading time. What i wanted to do is to create an application that acts as a shell for the big, and that shell just loads those apps as modules or something, to be lazyloaded or pre-loaded, and that would make the big app work smoothly.

I want to do that with keeping the development process work correctly though.

I imagine we will be having structure like this

```
projects/
   app1
   app2
   app3
   app4
app/
   app.module.ts
   app.component.ts
   ...
```

and so on, so that those apps, cloned using git.

what i currently have is

```
app/
  app.module.ts
  app.component.ts
  modules/
    app1
    app2
    app3
    app4
```

where they are one project, but this won't work because it would be hellish if people were working on about 7 apps in one project.

the question is, is it possible to lazy load a module from another project ?

```
{path: 'app1', loadChildren: '../projects/app1/src/app.module#AppModule'}
```

If it's possible how would the above code be ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really don't think that its possible lazy loading between the separate angular projects. But yeah there it is possible of doing so using the angular-cli with multiple app (each app representing different project) inside same cli project.

Please refer this link for having multiple app inside same cli project.

> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps
>
> https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/

Now its is possible to have lazy routes between those app(s). These links should help you get started.

> https://github.com/gatimus/multiple-apps-lazy-loading
>
> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8321

Hope this helps.